# Stopping Click Function when another class is Selected

Tags: jquery, events, click

If I have the following snippet to execute on the click of the button class.  Most of the buttons within the app are grouped in columns to a parent div with an id.

On a certain event where a tabbed element get highlighted or selected, I want to disable the click function below and all click functions for the parent button and all the children elements within the column.  Once the tabbed elements are deselected, I would like to enable the click functions back to normal.  What is the simplest form to enable/disable click functions when certain events occur.

```
 $('.button')on(mouseup, function(evt){
      doSomething(this);
      doSomethingElse(this)'
 });
```

EDIT: I do not want to change the snippet of code above. I just want to stop the click function completely if a class exists somewhere else completely separate from the button.

Comment: Without modifying none of those 4 lines of code, you can't

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a class on the items you want to ignore.

EX:

```
$('.button')on(mouseup, function(evt){
    if($(this).hasClass(className) {
      doSomething(this);
    }
    else {
      doSomethingElse(this);
    }
 });
```

Comment: I do not want to change that snippet of code at all b/c I have a hundred button, icons on the page.  Its more along the lines of what do I need to add to stop the snippet from executing if a certain class on a completely separate element is selected.